# MAX YTD value with an array formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a rectangular array of numbers, and I want to calculate the MAX value YearToDate. I want to use a dynamic array formula.

Let me explain:

[image]

I could theoretically use the MAX function in order to calculate a running MAX. However, the result table would not expand as the original "Tabla" expands.

I am able to calculate a running MAX using the SCAN function:

[image]

However, this formula deals only with one column of data, not with many.

My goal now is to "wrap" this SCAN function with a BYCOL function, so that all columns are taken into account.

However, in all my attemps so far, I have been unsuccessful. I'd like a formula with BYCOL/SCAN or another formula that yields a similar result.

I have tried, for example ...

[image]

... but I do not get the desired result.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to accept a volatile set-up:

`=SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET(INDEX(Tabla,1,1),,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(Tabla),0),SEQUENCE(ROWS(Tabla))))`

I have a strong suspicion that a succinct, non-volatile set-up does not exist, though I may be proved wrong.

Comment: Joss,
Your formula works very well, even if it uses a volatile function (OFFSET)

Answer (score 3):

We can use MAKEARRAY to do this:

```
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(Table1[#Data]),COLUMNS(Table1[#Data]),LAMBDA(a,b,MAX(INDEX(Table1[#Data],1,b):INDEX(Table1[#Data],a,b))))
```

[image]

Comment: I was proved wrong! Great solution.

Comment: Scott,
Excellent formula, it works perfectly for me. 
Just a comment, do you know if the LAMBDA in your formula calculates row-wise or column-wise?  for the case of your formula, this is not important, but it might be important in other use cases.

Comment: @vsoler I do not know.